# $C$ be a subring of $B$ which is again a subring of $A$ , let $A,B,C$ be Noetherian and $A \cong C$ , then is $A \cong B$?

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian, artinian, ring-homomorphism

Let $C$ be a subring of $B$ which is again a subring of a commutative  ring $A$ , also suppose all of $A,B,C$ are Noetherian and $A \cong C$ , then is it true that $A \cong B$ ? If the claim is not true then what happens if we assume all the rings $A,B,C$ are Artinian ?

( all rings and subrings are with unity , where for subrings the unity is inherited from the super-ring structure )

Comment: It is not clear, do you mean $C\subset B \subset A$?

Comment: No. Let $C = \mathbb C$ be the complex field, $B=\mathbb C(x)$, and $A = \overline{\mathbb C(x)}$ be an algebraic closure of $B$.

Comment: @Hamed : yes exactly that .... how was it not clear ? I clearly said which is a subring of which ...

Comment: (1) $\overline{\mathbb C(x)}$ is not an algebraic extension of $\mathbb C$, but it is an algebraically closed field that has the same transcendence degree over its prime field as $\mathbb C$, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. (2), yes, you can take $B=\mathbb C[x]$. (3) $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, but $\mathbb C(x)$ is not. It is missing $\sqrt{x}$, for example.

Comment: @KeithKearnes : Oh yes you are right it is not an algberaic extension of complex field ... your argument  is pretty high level for me to follow :p

Comment: @KeithKearnes : Could you also please elaborate why $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C(x)$ are not isomorphic ?

Comment: $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C(x)$ are not isomorphic because only one is algebraically closed. It is straight forward to show if $k \cong k'$ and $k$ is algebraically closed then so is $k'$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-artinian example, but which is "easier" than the one in the comments. Consider a situation like $$\mathbb C[x^n] \subset R\subset \mathbb C[x]$$ the outer two rings being isomorphic (send $x\mapsto x^n$). Now, it is easy to find subrings in between that are not isomorphic, for example if $n=3$ we could take $$R = \mathbb C[x^2,x^3] \cong \mathbb C[z,w]/(z^3 - w^2),$$ which is the coordinate ring of a cusp.

Comment: $x \to x^n$ is that a ring homomorphism ?

Comment: Yes. Maps out of $\mathbb C[x]$ are determined by where you send $x$, and any choice is acceptable. There is a universal property, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Quotient_ring_of_K.5BX.5D). ("maps" here means homomorphisms of $\mathbb C$-algebras.)