# $H,K$ be subgroups of an infinite abelian group $G$ such that $K \subseteq H$ and $G \cong K$ , then is it true that $G\cong H$ ?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Let $H,K$ be subgroups of an infinite abelian group $G$ such that $K \subseteq H$ and $G \cong K$ , then is it true that $G\cong H$ ?

( see related [$C$ be a subring of $B$ which is again a subring of $A$ , let $A,B,C$ be Noetherian and $A \cong C$ , then is $A \cong B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906406/c-be-a-subring-of-b-which-is-again-a-subring-of-a-let-a-b-c-be-noether)  )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so. How about $\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Q \subset \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Q \oplus \mathbb Z \subseteq \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Q\oplus\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Dang, beat me to it! +1.

Comment: By 16 seconds! Ha.

Comment: @BenDyer : It would have worked even if we took direct product instead of direct sum right ? Say $G:=\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \times ...$ , then $G \cong G \times G $ , $ G \subseteq \mathbb Z \times G \subseteq G \times G$ and $G$ is divisible but $\mathbb Z \times G$ is not ... am I right ?

Comment: Yeah, any infinite dimensional $\mathbb Q$ vector space will work there.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $G=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{Q}, +)$, let $K=\{g\in G: g(0)=g(2)=g(4)=...=0\}$ (that is, $K$ is "half" of $G$), and let $$H=\{g\in G: g(2)=g(4)=g(6)=...=0\mbox{ and }g(0)\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$ That is, $K\cong G$ and $H\cong G\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.